# How to disable enter when autocomplete option not selected: Google Maps SearchBox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps Searchbox with autocomplete:

If a user enters a name that displays results, and hit Enter before selecting an actual result, the 'places_matched' event still fires and the API chooses a result for them.

How can I force the user to select/highlight an autocomplete result, or at least detect somewhere that they didn't actually select a result and block the request?

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rs1mgno/2/

In the text input, enter anything, and hit enter. I type 'testing' and it outputs "BYU Testing Center". I want nothing to happen, since they didn't actually select an option.

Here's the JS code from the fiddle:

```
 $(function(){      
 var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var options = {
      keyword: 'establishment'
    }
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);

    searchBox.addListener('places_changed',     function(evt) {
      console.log('changed');

      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        $('#output').append(place['name']);
      });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

There are a lot of similar questions here on SO, but none that match this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) and the [Places Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) and mimic the behavior of the SearchBox. Using `getPlacePredictions` you can easily control the behavior of your search field and the search results items.

This example already has a bit of CSS that makes it look "like" the SearchBox. You can adapt and enhance of course. The code is commented so it should speak for itself.

```js
var autocompleteService, placesService, results, map;

function initialize() {

  results = document.getElementById('results');

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 50)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Bind listener for address search
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('address'), 'input', function() {

    results.style.display = 'block';
    getPlacePredictions(document.getElementById('address').value);
  });

  // Show results when address field is focused (if not empty)
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('address'), 'focus', function() {

    if (document.getElementById('address').value !== '') {

      results.style.display = 'block';
      getPlacePredictions(document.getElementById('address').value);
    }
  });

  // Hide results when click occurs out of the results and inputs
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'click', function(e) {

    if ((e.target.parentElement.className !== 'pac-container') && (e.target.parentElement.className !== 'pac-item') && (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT')) {

      results.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
}

// Get place predictions
function getPlacePredictions(search) {

  autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
    input: search,
    types: ['establishment', 'geocode']
  }, callback);
}

// Get place details
function getPlaceDetails(placeId) {

  var request = {
    placeId: placeId
  };

  placesService.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

      var center = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
      });

      map.setCenter(center);

      // Hide autocomplete results
      results.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

// Place search callback
function callback(predictions, status) {

  // Empty results container
  results.innerHTML = '';

  // Place service status error
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    results.innerHTML = '<div class="pac-item pac-item-error">Your search returned no result. Status: ' + status + '</div>';
    return;
  }

  // Build output for each prediction
  for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {

    // Insert output in results container
    results.innerHTML += '<div class="pac-item" data-placeid="' + prediction.place_id + '" data-name="' + prediction.terms[0].value + '"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span>' + prediction.description + '</div>';
  }

  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-item");

  // Results items click
  for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {

    item.onclick = function() {

      getPlaceDetails(this.dataset.placeid);
    };
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.search {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.pac-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 170px;
}

.pac-icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png);
  background-size: 34px;
}

.pac-icon-marker {
  background-position: -1px -161px;
}

.pac-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  color: #999;
}

.pac-item:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.pac-item-error,
.pac-item-error:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <input id="address" placeholder="Enter address" type="text" tabindex="1" />
  <br />
  <div id="results" class="pac-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rs1mgno/4/) with the solution. The idea is quite simple after knowing the searchbox caches up to 5 results everytime you have a key stroke locally in your DOM tree until you have a match. They are cached in the `div.pac-container` element.

```
 $(function(){      
   var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
   var options = {
      keyword: 'establishment'
   }
   var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);

   searchBox.addListener('places_changed',  function(evt) {

     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     if ($('.pac-item').length > 0) {
       return;
     }

     places.forEach(function(place) {
       $('#output').append(place['name']);
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: While this might work (today), it relies on a class (the `.pac-item` one) and if Google changes their class name in their next release, then your code will stop working.

Answer (score 2):

If user press enter nothing will happen.

**Edit 3:**

```js
$(function(){      
 var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var options = {
      keyword: 'establishment'
    }
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function () {

      var place = searchBox.getPlace();
      if(place.address_components != null && place.address_components.length >= 1){
        console.log(place.address_components.length);
        $('#output').append(place['name']);
      }
      

  });
    
});
```

```css
body {         
    font:14px sans-serif;           
} 
input {
    margin: 0.6em 0.6em 0; 
    width:398px;
}
#map_canvas {         
    height: 400px;         
    width: 400px;         
    margin: 0.6em;       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=us&language=en&sensor=false"></script>
<input id="pac-input" type="text" size="50">             
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution gives error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`.

Comment: my bad, replace `e with evt`

Comment: `evt` is undefined. Please check [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) there is not any `arg` pass to the `event`.

Comment: You've tried well, just little more afford needed. You can solve this.

Comment: @csharpbd `searchBox.addListener('places_changed',  function(evt) {` you can see `evt` is defined, :)

Comment: Please check in `console`, the value of `evt` is undefined.

Comment: Please check now. I used different approach. :)